# How can I make if statements right in powershell

Tags: powershell-ise

I just start doing something with PowerShell and want to make code in which for example I can press 1 and then I take off clock from desktop, but when I press 2 it will be back in his old place. I just don't get that PowerShell syntax. I need some example how to do things like this

Thanks

Comment: Add whatever code you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

```
$x = Read-Host "Enter 1 or 2:"

if ($x -eq "1") {
    # put code to remove clock here

} elif ($x -eq "2") {
    # put code to reinstate clock here

} else {
    Write-Host "You didn't enter 1 or 2"
}
```